# Google People API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I try to implement People API, after **successfully** OAuth2, when try to load people, error is:

```
Undefined property: Google_Service_People_Resource_People::$connections
```

This is lines who produce error:

```
$people_service = new Google_Service_People($client);
$connections = $people_service->people->connections->listConnections('people/me');
```

Am going by this tutorial https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started,
and this: https://developers.google.com/people/v1/requests.

Thanks

Comment: We would love to help, but if we can't see your attempt through code, we don't know where to start :(

Comment: Sorry :/, I just update question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for...

```
$connections = $people_service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! Could you tell me where is proper documentation? Also I want to display emails and phone numbers, but with this get only names...

Comment: `$optParams = array('pageSize' => 100, 'requestMask.includeField' => 'person.phone_numbers,person.names,person.email_addresses');$connections = $people_service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('‌​people/me', $optParams);`

Comment: Right, even I can't find that info anywhere in the documentation. Did you go through the source files for this @BA_Webimax?

Answer (score 2):

We've written a PHP Google People API library that might help. It makes implementing access to Google Contacts via the Google People API much easier than using Google's own library.

Link: https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api

## Example Usage

### Usage

#### Retrieve all contacts

```
// Retrieval all contacts
foreach($people->all() as $contact) {
    echo $contact->resourceName.' - ';
    if ($contact->names) {
        echo $contact->names[0]->displayName;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Retrieve a single contact

```
// Retrieve single contact (by resource name)
$contact = $people->get('people/c8055020007701654287');
```

#### Create a new contact

```
// Create new contact
$contact = new Contact($people);
$contact->names[0] = new stdClass;
$contact->names[0]->givenName = 'Testy';
$contact->names[0]->familyName = 'McTest Test';
$contact->save();
```

#### Update a contact

```
// Update contact
$contact->names[0]->familyName = 'McTest';
$contact->save();
```

#### Delete a contact

```
// Delete contact
$contact->delete();
```

Comment: I tried this package, but it always shows refresh token as blank. Any Idea?